# C# Problem with a List Displaying in a Textbox

Tags: c#, list, textbox

I have a small application that has several checkboxes, a submit button, and a textbox. I want the user to be able to check what they want, click the submit button, and have the results display in the textbox. The application runs but instead of the values displaying I get "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" displayed in the textbox. I am very new to this and would appreciate any help. My code is as follows...

```
namespace MY_App
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<string> ls = new List<string>();

    private void Checkbox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
                ls.Add( "P.C. ");
    }

    private void Checkbox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            ls.Add( "WYSE Terminal" );
    }

    private void Checkbox3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ls.Add("Dual Monitors "); 
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string line = string.Join(",", ls.ToString());
        textBoxTEST.Text = line;

    }

    private void textBoxTEST_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to concat the object name, because of `ls.ToString()` will returns exactly what you've got in your `TextBox`.

Instead, use the following:

```
string line = string.Join(",", ls.ToArray());
textBoxTEST.Text = line;
```

Also, here is Linq solution:

```
ls.Aggregate((i, j) => i + ","+ j)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thanks for the help and the fast response. I'll mark this correct as soon as STACK will allow (about 5 more mins)...

Answer (score 3):

`ls.ToString()` calls `Object.ToString`, i.e., the List class does not presume to know how you would like to print out its internal values.  If you want to create a display string you will need to pass in an array of strings to `String.Join`, not the output of `List<T>.ToString()`.

```
string line = string.Join(",", ls.ToArray());
textBoxTEST.Text = line;
```

Answer (score 3):

The first problem you have is with your CheckChanged events.  They should probably only add to the List under two conditions.  The first is the CheckBox.IsChecked == true and if they don't already exist in the list.

You shouldn't use string.Join with ls.ToString().  Use ToArray.

to handle the SelectionChanged:

```
private void myCheckBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)  
{
    myTextBox.Text = myCheckBox.IsChecked ? myTextBox.Text = "The Value" : myTextBox.Text = string.Empty;   
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in real time? I.E. The user checks the box and the item is added to the textbox. If unchecked it is taken out of the checkbox and do away with the button_click event?

Comment: Sure.  You can handle the ListBox SelectionChanged Event.  Populate the TextBox if the checkbox's IsChecked property is true.  Clear the TextBox if it's false.  I updated my answer above.

Comment: This is awesome. I think I will rewrite my little app to behave like this. It seems to make a little more sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to rewrite your button click event:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
Foreach( var item in ls)
{
 sb.Append(String.Format("{0} , ",item));
}
textboxTEST.Text = sb.ToString();
```

You could even change this so that after your last item you don't get the " , " but i think you can solve that. :)